# What is the background script that Super User is using to automatically update content without reloading the page?

Tags: support

I am pretty much interested to know what is the background script that Super User (any Stack Exchange community for that matter) is using to automatically update the content of webpage without reloading the page?

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works. However I'm sure that it uses AJAX. Whenever an event (new question, new answer, etc.) happens then through AJAX it updates the content. If you want to know about AJAX you can start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: The technologies used are AJAX for content delivery and Websockets for user notifications. The script itself depends on the back-end configuration.

Comment: User notification you mean the response we get for any activity done ? @Spokey

Comment: @learner1 For example the pop-up that says how many new questions were asked since you last refreshed, the notification when someone up/down votes you or you get new reply. Clicking the actual notification will then trigger an AJAX request to return the data. Websockets create an on-going connection to the server to receive and respond to messages, but it's rarely used to actually deliver the content (use ajax instead)

Comment: @Spokey Actually, it's called "[Francis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28comics%29)"

Comment: http://builtwith.com/superuser.com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super User is part of the Stack Exchange network. Stack Exchange is a closed-source platform, and is built on a variety of closed and open source software. The general architecture is described on Meta Stack Exchange and is updated periodically:

#### [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange network](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370)

Background refresh is powered by websockets, using [a custom C# websockets server developed in-house called NetGain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168145/sockets-used-by-stack-overflow/168148#168148), which [is now open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/NetGain). Dynamic interface elements are achieved using jQuery.